# Align items to left with ngFor

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, ngfor

I have a div and I want to add some inputs in it dynamically and since the inputs are supposed to make a number with a format, I add `justify-content-end` class to start from left.
HTML:

```
<div class='row justify-content-end'>
  <ng-container *ngFor='let input of dashAndInputCount; let i = index'>
     <button (click)='addDashAndInput(i)'> - </button>
     <div class='col-2' style='padding-top: 2.2rem !important;'>
        <input type='number'></input>
     </div>
     <div class='col-1 ax-text-center'>
        <p>
          ــ
        </p>
     </div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

TS:

```
  addDashAndInput(i) {
    this.dashAndInputCount.push(1);
  }
```

Now the problem is that when I add an item, the item is added in a wrong direction. For instance if I add 1, 2, 3, 4 in the row I'll have 4, 3, 2, 1. How can I fix this?

Comment: use unshift to add new one to beginning. this.dashAndInputCount.unshift(1);

Comment: Your solution sounds rational to me but not to the code unfortunately! @NaeimFard

Answer (score 1):

justify-content Property is dependent on **display: flex**
You should add **display: flex** to the justify-content-end class

```
.justify-content-end{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: end;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Include d-flex  class in the containter. With d-flex the element behaves like a block element and lays out its content according to the [flexbox model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout).